# UIScrollView auto scrolls to bottom during change to landscape orientation

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a scrollview with 2 UITextViews (neither are editable). When a change to landscape orientation occurs, the scollview inexplicably scrolls to the bottom. This behaviour does not occur when rotating to portrait. I have tried setting the scrollEnabled property before rotation to NO, but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found that by setting the scrollview contentsize to 0 before rotation and restoring it during or after rotation prevents this unwanted auto scrolling